# Magento 2: Product page images

Tags: magento2, product-images

Depending on the dimensions / ratio of the product page image, I'm sometimes left with images with a large white band above and below the image – especially on 'landscape' shaped images. Is there a way to make the product page gallery 'wrap' the image and not show any white space above / below the image?